# How to structure my Controllers / Classes in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I am building as app and have different controllers per object. One Controller I have is, let's say, `Car`, and then I have separate controllers for `engine`, `wheels`, `chassis`, `GPS`

I know that for my car to access the wheels methods i can use:

```
class Car extends Wheels
```

But then how can my Car class also access the methods in the Engine, Chassis and GPS classes.

As I understand it, I can't extend to multiple classes. So do I just need to replicate the relevant Wheels methods in Car. It seems inefficient.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need -https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php. Check it please.

Comment: you can use TRAITS concept for this